# linux permission denied ./file.sh VS bash file.sh

Tags: bash, sh, permission-denied

I have the following file `xx.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi"
```

The permissions are defined as follows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     22 Nov 22 10:55 xx.sh*
```

but when I run the file `./xx.sh` I get:

```
**-bash: ./xx.sh: Permission denied**
```

When running with override: `bash xx.sh` it runs correctly.

What is the permission issue here?

Comment: What are the permissions of the parent folder `/`?

Comment: all the upper folders have the same permission 777

Comment: Is it then possible that your user can't execute `/bin/bash` (the shebang line)? This is the only difference b/n the 2 ways of execution you describe.

Comment: `findmnt -l | grep noexec` - check if your file system is mounted with `noexec`.

Comment: Right! See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203371/run-script-sh-vs-bash-script-sh-permission-denied

Comment: correct. thank you very mach

Answer (score 1):

Your system is probably mounted with `noexec`. Verify by:

```sh
findmnt <folder>
```

If you have `noexec` in the OPTIONS, then you are not allowed to execute executable binaries in the mounted file system. You can solve using the [`mount`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) command.

Comment: correct , thank you